# Why is an /etc/fstab entry not automatically mounted?

Tags: mount, linux-mint, fstab

I want to mount my QNAP windows shares as a share in Linux mint (18.1). I have created the following entry in `/etc/fstab`

```
# Mount share from samba server
//192.168.178.4/files   /media/share/d  cifs    credentials=/home/arnold/.credentials,iocharset=utf8,rw,iocharset=utf8,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777 0   0
```

It is not mounted when the machine starts and I log in. I have to issue `sudo mount -a` to get it mounted. I had the impression that `/etc/fstab`  entries were automatically mounted. Is there a way to get this partition automatically mounted during startup?

Answer (score 0):

## `auto`

I think you need to add `auto` to the list of mount options, like:

```
# Mount share from samba server
//192.168.178.4/files   /media/share/d  cifs    credentials=/home/arnold/.credentials,iocharset=utf8,auto,rw,iocharset=utf8,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777    0   0
```

I know it doesn't really make sense, but maybe it's worth a try?

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work. As I gathered from the man pages it seems to be the default. Thanks anyway! This problem is pestering me for a week.